# Dependency Injection & connection strings / Multiple instances of a singleton

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Web Api project which relies heavily on Azure Cosmos DB. Until now, having one Cosmos DB account (one connection string) was sufficient. Now a new requirement is to be able to connect to a different Cosmos (two connection strings) depending on an incoming parameter.

For customerId X we should fetch documents from Cosmos DB 1 and for another customer Y we have to look in Cosmos DB 2.

Until now my Startup.cs file registered a singleton instance of CosmosClient. Which in turn gets instantiated like this
cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endpointUrl, primaryKey);
And this worked really well. The Web Api was easily able to process all requests. But now that we have to new up a CosmosClient per request, performance is really bad.

So my question is; Is there a way to have multiple instances of the same singleton? As in; can we create a single instance of the combination Class+EndPointUrl? (Would that still be a singleton?)

Right now, we are newing up thousands of CosmosClients every minute. And we really need just one more compared to what we had earlier.

Comment: This might get you pointed in the right direction. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/httpclientfactory-cosmos-db-net-sdk/

Comment: In our application we ended up creating a dictionary of CosmosClient objects (key being the account name) and injected a singleton instance of that dictionary.

Comment: There are only 2 databases and you connect to one or the other depending on who the user is? In that case I'd register two CosmosClient instances in Startup.cs, one for each database, and decide when the request comes in which of the two to use.

Comment: You didn't say what DI framework you're using - Autofac supports "keyed" registrations pretty easily. https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html

Comment: I'm using standard .NET Framework DI.

Comment: I am now looking to first see if we can reuse one and the same HttpClient on the CosmosClients we are instantiating, by using those CosmosClientOptions. But, still strugling to find a good example on how to use that in our scenario.

Comment: All these suggestions look very promising. Either as a quick fix or as a starting point for some more extensive rework. Thanks for that! But, would it be worth / possible to move from comments to answers? So that we can have some examples and elaborate a bit more on each specific solution? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all comments and answers.

In the end, is this case, the best solution was the approach that was suggested by Mr. T. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/httpclientfactory-cosmos-db-net-sdk/

I'm now still using one CosmosClient, Scoped. Which allows dynamic use of endpoints.

By injecting the IHttpClientFactory and setting the CosmosClientOptions like this;

```
  {
      HttpClientFactory = () => _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("cosmos")
  });
```

we are now making full use of the HttpClient and its ability to reuse ports.

Comment: Can you post an expanded version of your code? How does using a named HTTP client allow you to connect to multiple cosmos instances? Where are you setting the connection string for cosmos / how are you differentiating between the different connections?

Comment: Agree with @Trevor.Screws. Please provide more details, thanks!

Comment: @Tys scoped? Could you share more information, please?

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to do this, but an easy implementation would be to create a wrapper around each `CosmosClient` you use. The only use of the wrapper will be to allow you to use various instances of the `CosmosClient` and differentiate them by their types.

```cs
//Create your own class for each client inheriting the behaviour of CosmosClient
public class ContosoCosmosClient : CosmosClient
{
    public ContosoCosmosClient(string connectionString, CosmosClientOptions clientOptions = null) : base(connectionString, clientOptions)
    {
    }

    public ContosoCosmosClient(string accountEndpoint, string authKeyOrResourceToken, CosmosClientOptions clientOptions = null) : base(accountEndpoint, authKeyOrResourceToken, clientOptions)
    {
    }

    public ContosoCosmosClient(string accountEndpoint, TokenCredential tokenCredential, CosmosClientOptions clientOptions = null) : base(accountEndpoint, tokenCredential, clientOptions)
    {
    }
}
```

```cs
//In Startup.up add a Singleton for each client
services.AddSingleton(new ContosoCosmosClient(...));
services.AddSingleton(new FabrikamCosmosClient(...));
```

Then in your business logic you can add both clients and depending on your logic choose which client you want to use:

```cs
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(ContosoCosmosClient contosoClient, FabrikamCosmosClient fabrikamClient)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```